# rails 5.1 simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

alguem me ajuda com o simple form... estou tentando colocar uma mascara no meu simple form inicialmente tentei da seguinte forma

```
:input_html => {:maxlength => 14, :"data-mask" => "999.999.999-99"}
```

não funcionou então tentei

```
:data => {:mask=> '999-999-9999'}
```

que também não funcinou. Estou usando o simple form... se alguem puder me ajuda agradesço desde ja. Uso a versão 5.1 do rails

Comment: Tenta:  data: { mask: '999-999-9999' }

Comment: Não deu certo, essas opções me parecem estar corretas sabe se tem q ativar algo?

Comment: você importou a biblioteca da mascara ?

Comment: não entendi mto bem... se eu fiz o bundle?

Comment: isso, qual plugin de mascara você ta usando ?

Comment: não estou usando nenhum plugin de mascara, eu to tentando acessar propriedades do html5 que ja possui mascara, sou novato em rails se tiver coisas melhores pfv me recomende rsrsr

Comment: Você sabe como incluir arquivos js no seu projeto ?

Comment: pelo asset pipeline no arquivo.coffee

Comment: Eu sempre uso esse plugin jQuery pra fazer as mascaras: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask  bem facil de usar, se não conseguir pergunte aq de novo